# BigDecimal methods send formatted numbers

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to round my big BigDecimals off to three decimal places. For instance, let's say I have some

```
BigDecimal  X = 1362.59633
```

I wanna get:

```
1362.596
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
BigDecimal Y = X.round(new MathContext(3));
```

But I keep getting this: 1.36E+3.
What should I do in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the [Javadoc for `BigDecimal.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString())? (And related `toPlainString`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    BigDecimal  X = new BigDecimal(1362.59633);
    X = X.setScale(3,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(X); //1362.596
```

> Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of this method
>   do not result in the original object being modified, contrary to the
>   usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X. Instead,
>   setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the returned object
>   may or may not be newly allocated.

Comment: Why do you duplicate my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't have to round but you have to set the scale of your `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal X = new BigDecimal("1362.59633");
X = X.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(X.doubleValue());
```

This will print out `1362.596`.

*Note that `setScale` returns a new `BigDecimal` so you have to assign it like I did in my example.*

**edit:** there are several kinds of rounding strategies. Check the `BigDecimal` class for reference. I edited my answer to use `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`.

Comment: The only thing about this metho is that it returns for 1362.59633 = 1362.597. How can I fix that? I wanna get 1362.596

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal y= x.round(new MathContext(7, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only `double` you can do

```
double d = 1362.59633;
double d2 = Math.round(d * 1e3) / 1e3;
System.out.println(d2);
```

prints

```
1362.596
```

Note: this doesn't create any objects to perform the rounding.

Comment: The caption mentions BigDecimal, not double.

Answer (score 0):

We can use DecimalFormat class to define the format of the double data. You can define like ***new DecimalFormat("####.000")***

we can call format method the value you want.

Example
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("####.000");
format.format("1362.59633");

Answer (score 0):

- First set the scale to 3 using [`setScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) with [`RoundingMode.DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) as the rounding mode to truncate
- Then call [`toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29) to guarantee the return of a String representation without an exponent field
- Calling [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) on a `BigDecimal` does not guarantee the return of a `String` without an exponent. It returns the string representation using scientific notation if an exponent is needed

An example based on your question:

```
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf( 1362.59633 );
System.out.println( x.setScale( 3, RoundingMode.DOWN ).toPlainString( ) );
```